# typeerror: int object not iterable in python

Tags: python, iteration, typeerror

I got the error `Int object not iterable` but there is no iteration in that line. What is the problem with the line `n += char` ?

```
def checkio(data):

    n = []
    for char in data[:]:
       if data.count(char) > 1:
           n += char       
    return n
```

Comment: type(data) may be integer?

Answer (score 0):

In **Python** the `+=` operator is overloaded for `list` values as an alias to `list.extend()`.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst += [4, 5]
# lst now is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst.extend([4, 5])
```

It looks like you are attempting to track the number of instances of `char` in `data` when char is repeated, which you likely want to use a `dict` for.

```
n = {}
for char in data:
    if char not in n:
        n[char] = 1
    else:
        n[char] += 1
return n
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix!

**Note:** You can just use `append()` in lieu of if you'd like. If you're trying to build a second list without duplicates, youll need to add a check within the `if` conditional that checks to see if `char` is in `n`.

```
def checkio(data):
    n = []
    for char in data[:]: # not sure why the copy of data here!
       if data.count(char) > 1:
           n += [char] # add the [] since the += operator is overloaded for list
    return n
```

Outputs:

```
def checkio(data):
    n = []
    for char in data[:]:
        if data.count(char) > 1:
            n += [char]
    return n

>>> d1 = [1, 2, 2, 4, 1]
>>> checkio(d1)
[1, 2, 2, 1]
>>>
```